# Using sed, awk or grep to split a string with numbers

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have this file:

```
mmD_154Lbb_e_dxk_83233.orc
154L_bbe_Bddxk_3259.txt
14Lbe_3233.orc
m2_154Lbbe_dxk_67233.op
mZZ_1A4Lbbe_dxk_32823.op
mmD_154Lbbe_dxk_99333.orc
mmD_oS154be_dxk_12338.txt
```

I'm trying to use sed or awk to split the numbers and I don't have solution:

I need out put:

```
83233
2597
3233
67233
32823
99333
12338
```

How can I get it to split on each delimiter?

Thanks

Comment: Where does the 2597 come from?

Comment: Have you tried looking up regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk can get you that:

```
awk -F '[_.]' '{print $(NF-1)}' file
83233
3259
3233
67233
32823
99333
12338
```

Comment: This is also returning the parsed line when no digits are found: (eg: `echo 'test.txt | awk -F '[_.]' '{print $(NF-1)}'` return `test.txt`)

Comment: Do you know the requirement for such input?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\..*$//;s/^.*_//' file
       |       | 
       |       > remove all chars from beginning until last '_' char
       > remove last '.' char and all chars after that
```

**output**

```
83233
3259
3233
67233
32823
99333
12338
```

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

with GNU sed

```
sed 's/^.*_\([[:digit:]]\+\)\..*$/\1/' file
```

Comment: Not bad but this return the full line when no digits are matched